# .setEnabled only seems to be able to be toggled once

Tags: android, android-view, android-button

Is there a reason that .setEnabled() only seems to work once? I wish to toggle it on and off multiple times during an activity lifecycle depending on the content. i've tried wrapping it in switch statements.

```
        GAME_STATE_INPLAY = true;       
        if (GAME_STATE_INPLAY = true) {
            explainButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    ....
        if (c.getString(7).toString().length() > 0) {
                explainButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Elaborate please. What activity life cycle are you using?

Comment: Is it if (GAME_STATE_INPLAY == true) ?

Comment: no no, i didn't mean to be so specific with the lifecycle part.i just meant over the course of when the user needs that (trivia game screen open) and that boolean is just some arbitrary something i made up cause i was hoping that the problem would be fixed if it wasn't placed in on create all by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to get the btn by id again:

```
   if (GAME_STATE_INPLAY = true) {
        Button explainButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        explainButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (c.getString(7).toString().length() > 0) {
            Button explainButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            explainButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: crazy. it totally worked. is there something else i should i know about it? so i don't make the error again?

Comment: when you setEnabled to false the first time, the explainButton value stored didn't change, it changed programmatically on the display. so when you wanted to set it true again, the value was already true.